# How to solve 'Empty encoded password' error when trying to connect LDAP

Tags: ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP of the company and I am getting a lot of troubles. I solve one and suddenly I get a new one.
Right now I think the context is well defined and there is connectivity but it complains about 'Empty encoded password' and I dont know how to face it.
I am trying to authenticate through a service user.

Now I am working with this code:

```
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
    .userSearchBase("ou=xxxx,ou=yyyy")
    .userSearchFilter("SamAccountName={0}")
    .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://servername:389/dc=aaaa,dc=bbbb,dc=cccc")
            .managerDn("CN=serviceUserName,OU=uuuu,OU=yyyy,DC=aaaa,DC=bbbb,DC=cccc")
            .managerPassword("serviceUserPass")
    .and()
        .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("password");
```

And:

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

And I am having this error:

> 2019-05-13 10:41:37.808  WARN 22928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Empty encoded password
>   2019-05-13 10:41:37.926 ERROR 22928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
>
> org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090D70, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db1

I try changing the PasswordEncoder function to:

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            return BCrypt.hashpw(rawPassword.toString(), BCrypt.gensalt(4));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            return BCrypt.checkpw(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);
        }
    };
    }
```

And I check that the 'encodedPassword' variable is empty (The 'rawPassword' is the one I enter in the login page). This error is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: salt cannot be null

I don't know if it means it doesn't have access to LDAP, if the password can't be encoded, if it doesn't find the user...

Any help is really appreciate.

Comment: I'm guessing that the attribute in Active Directory is not named "password", but "userPassword" or "unicodePwd" depending on your server's settings.

Comment: Same problem with any of these that you suggest me